# Select value in column that matches value in list (UPDATED FOR CLARITY)

Tags: list, powerquery

If I have a column of street addresses and want to select only the address's directional, what syntax would I use to accomplish that in Excel Power Query?

For instance, how do I get "NE" from "357 Pyrite Dr NE" even if the address is incorrectly formatted as "357 NE Pyrite Dr" or "357 Pyrite NE Dr"? Likewise, how would I get "NW" from "506 Mark NW St"?

As far as I can figure out, I would hit add column > custom column and enter a syntax similar to the following...

= if List.ContainsAny([Address], {"NE", "NW", "SE", "SW"}) = TRUE then Text.Select([Address], {"NE", "NW", "SE", "SW"} else null

...except I know that's not the correct syntax since it always produces an error. The same thing happens when I replace "Text.Select" with "List.Select" in the above formula.

---

---

For greater clarification, I'm posting the query as it stands now, whittled down to one column from a table with 100 columns and 4000 rows:

```
let

Source = q_NMAACC,

#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Address - Street 1", "Address - Street 2"}),

#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Removed Other Columns",{"Address - Street 1", "Address - Street 2"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.None),"Street Address"),

#"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Merged Columns",{{"Street Address", Text.Trim, type text}}),

#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Trimmed Text", each [Street Address] <> null and [Street Address] <> "")

in

#"Filtered Rows"
```

Here are the first 25 rows to give you some data to work off.

| Street Address |
| --- |
| PO Box 3416 Nr57 #165a |
| 1016 Copper NE Ave Apt C |
| 217 Garcia St NE |
| 232 17th St SE |
| 560 60th St NW |
| 2935 Madeira Dr NE |
| 9677 Eagle Ranch Rd NW Apt 415 |
| 5320 Roanoke Ave NW |
| 17 Hwy 304 |
| HCR 79 Box 46 |
| 6524 Camino Rojo |
| 3518 Vail Ave SE |
| 6412 Torreon Dr NE |
| 6136 Flor de Rio Ct NW |
| 1712 36th Street SE |
| 734 Columbia Street |
| 716 Morning Meadows Dr NE |
| 6601 Tennyson St NE Apt 10207 |
| Alamo - Rio Salado PO Box 804 |
| 206 Aragon Rd |
| 6901 Verano Ct NW |
| 6709 Siesta Pl NE |
| 10 Meadow Hills Loop |
| 98 Avenida Jardin |
| 6903 Prairie Rd NE Apt 216 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
List={"NE","NW","SW","SE"},
LocateTable = Table.FromList(List, null, {"Locate"}),
Find = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Found",  (x) => Text.Combine(Table.SelectRows(LocateTable, each Text.Contains(x[Address],[Locate], Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))[Locate],", "))
in Find
```

[image]

You could also use another table to contain the search criteria

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Find = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Found",  (x) => Text.Combine(Table.SelectRows(LocateTable, each Text.Contains(x[Address],[Locate], Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))[Locate],", "))
in Find
```

[image]

the **, Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase** part is ignoring case for comparison, which you can remove if you want to match case

Comment: Would you please explain (x) => and x next to [Address]?

Comment: It enables you to refer to current row in current table while filtering another table

Comment: Did the answer solve your question?

Comment: So Text.Contains(x[Address], Locate, Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) means show me the text in the current row of Table1's [Address] column... by searching for the text substring contained in the other table (LocateTable)...which other table (LocateTable) is being filtered to only show values that are equal to matching text substrings that are included in the current row of Table1's [Address] column...regardless of the case of the text substring?

Comment: Keep any row from LocateTable where there is a Text.Contains match from the current Table1 row to the dynamic row in LocateTable, as we sequence through all the rows in LocateTable, If this answer works, it is customary to accept it as solving the question by toggling the checkmark near the arrows instead of haggling over how it works, though this is fun too

Comment: If given 1 table with 1 column and 4000 rows (addresses), derived from a much bigger query based on a much bigger table, what syntax is needed to do the same thing (add 1 column with only the "directionals" from the first column in each row)? How do you do that without creating or referencing another table? I've appended my big question above with the syntax as it stands currently.